# Set activities below status Bar

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

When I deploy my app in iphone simulator, its taking the start of the activivity as the star of the screen, but as I hace controls at the top of some activities, the controls don't work because they are appearing on the status bar.

I need my pages start below the status bar as shown in the picture

I use ContentPages, but I don't know if it is a XAML property or I can do it from code

"Example of Iphone XS Max"

[image]

Even tho, it is happening on every device

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code in your pages XAML

```
xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"

             ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true"
```